# Search multiple indices against some index pattern using NEST

Tags: elasticsearch, search, wildcard, nest, elasticsearch-indices

I searched NEST docs but seems to cant find a proper answer for it. 
My question is how to search multiple indices against some index pattern using NEST?  e.g

if I have indices with following names in Elasticsearch DB

```
media-2017-10, media-2018-03, media-2018-04
```

For specifying my selected indices, I need to use wild card character * like this:

```
client.Search<Media>(s => s
   .Index("media-*")
   . query goes here .....
```

Is it possible in NEST ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this works. Try it :)

`.Index(...)` accepts wildcard indices

Answer (score 0):

You can also search in multiple indices in that way:

```
var allIndices = new[] {
        "media-*",
        "docs-*",
        "common-*"           
    };

Nest.Indices allIndices = allIndices;
return _elasticClient
            .SearchAsync<EsBaseModel>(s => s
                .Index( allIndices)
                .Size(_esConfig.MaxCallIDsSize)
                .RequestConfiguration(r => r.RequestTimeout(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)))
                .Query(q =>
                    q.Match(m => m.Field("fieldname").Query(condition))                        
                ));
```

**Steps:**

Just create an array with string indices.
Indices can be explicit or implicit **using any pattern** supported in Nest client docs.

Notice - neet to put attention to optimize the searching, since it could take a while to search in all the indices that you've provided.
(optimize can be achieved by ignoring very old dates, limit the results, etc...)